# Are all Type-2 Phasers used in TNG left-handed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, phaser

I got a model Type-2 phaser (The *TNG* one, not the *DS9/VOY* one).

[image: Phaser held with the left hand]

As you can see with this image, holding the phaser in my left hand has my fingers and palm resting on the grip.

[image: Phaser held with the right hand]

Holding the phaser with my right hand has my fingers and palm resting on the frame of the weapon.

Does the *Technical Manual* specify whether these weapons should be held left-handed by default?  Is there any indication during a *TNG* episode that Starfleet trains people to use these left-handed?  Are they used this way in the show?

I know they removed this with later versions that had the grip on the bottom only, but these didn't show up in *TNG*.

**Basically, is the Type-2 Phaser a left-handed weapon?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The phaser you've pictured is a *reversed* version of the "Cobra-Head" Type-2 phasers used in Season 3 of TNG onwards.

As you can see from this authentic TV prop (previously owned by Rick Sternbach, Senior Illustrator for Star Trek: TNG; who created the design) which was [auctioned](http://www.icollector.com/Star-Trek-The-Next-Generation-3rd-Season-working-hero-phaser_i8632602#) for slightly over £3000, the hand-grip was originally configured for a **right-handed** user.
[image]

[image]

Whereas his [original design sketch](http://www.ricksternbach.com/typeii.jpg) has the phaser in "left-handed" configuration

[image]

As you can see from the pictures below, the standard type 2 phaser used from season 3 of TNG onwards could be used in either configuration; Left-handed or right-handed.

[image]
**Troi in TNG: "Power Play"**

[image: Young Picard in TNG "Rascals]
**Young Picard in TNG "Rascals"**

The two subsidiary buttons were evidently used to dial the power settings up or down (between 1 and 16) with the larger button used as the trigger. There also appear to be other buttons under the body of the phaser that may be used to control range and modulation.

[image]

In the TNG episode "Redemption" Guinan uses her left hand during a target practice session with Worf. Since she is [normally right handed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eZrgUC8ixA), it can be surmised that she deliberately **switched** hands to give him a fighting chance against her superior skills.

[image]

Comment: Your first image is gone, I would have replaced it with an appropriate one, but I'm short on time atm...  and I'm feelin' too lazy.

Comment: I almost couldn't be bothered myself. It's such a lovely (and well-researched) answer to languish at zero votes :-(

Comment: I don't need your pity vote :-P !

Comment: lol, yes you do! :)

Comment: Rule of Acquisition 109 : Dignity and an empty sack is worth the sack

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Apparently not. As they are using their right hands in this scene here.

On the DS9 Phaser rifles, the black sections similar to these are actually the replaceable power packs (think of them as Ammo Magazines) But that may not be the case on the Type IIs

Comment: As pointed out in the now-deleted answer, the phaser in your picture is actually a different model (from the early seasons), so maybe this should be addressed.

Comment: @bitmask - I've addressed it in more detail in my answer. This answer is actually looking at the wrong phaser...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

as you can see the phaser is designed for use with the Starfleet uniform which has the com badge on the left so when they were in a firefight they can access the combadge without having to strain or put down their weapon